# Ember.js Railscast #410 undefined is not a function TypeError: at RandomRaffle.EntriesRoute.Ember.Route.extend.setupController

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm following the Ember.js Railscast episode 410.  When I change my router.js file from

```
RandomRaffle.EntriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller) {
    controller.set('content', []);
  }

});
```

to this

```
RandomRaffle.EntriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function (controller) {
    controller.set('content', RandomRaffle.Entry.find());
  }

});
```

I get the error:

Error while processing route: entries undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function at RandomRaffle.EntriesRoute.Ember.Route.extend.setupController

My models/entry.js file contains:

```
RandomRaffle.Entry = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  winner: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

My controllers/entries_controller.js contains:

```
RandomRaffle.EntriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
// newEntryName: "",

  actions: {

    addEntry: function () {
      RandomRaffle.Entry.createRecord({name: this.get('newEntryName')});
      this.set('newEntryName', "");
    },

    drawWinner: function () {
      this.setEach('highlight', false);
      var pool = this.rejectBy('winner');
      if (pool.length > 0){
        var entry = pool[Math.floor(Math.random() * pool.length)];
        entry.set('winner', true);
        entry.set('highlight', true);
        this.get('store').commit();
      }
    }

  }
});
```

javascripts/store.js

```
RandomRaffle.Store = DS.Store.extend({});

// Override the default adapter with the `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` which
// is built to work nicely with the ActiveModel::Serializers gem.
RandomRaffle.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you have to `find` in the `model` hook. Before `setupController`, add a function called `model` that `return RandomRaffle.Entry.find()`

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I've tried adding and replacing setupController with model function returning RandomRaffle.Entry.find().  I get the same errors.

Comment: To whomever edited in random code to this post, please know that adding code to a question is not acceptable. The only case where this is OK is if the OP has provided code in the comments and neglected to include it in the question itself.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That was me unfortunately.  I'm having trouble staying signed in so I mistakenly added code as anonymous.  Sorry and thanks for looking out.

Comment: No problem. Just so you know, that edit **should** have been rejected in the review queue (of course it wasn't, but thats a different problem...), so you'll want to make sure to make the edits as yourself so that they actually appear :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing your `store` is properly defined, you should create a [`model`](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/) function in your `route`, similar to this:

```
RandomRaffle.EntriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
       return RandomRaffle.Entry.find(); 

       // This is deprecated. Latest versions of ember-data use the following:
       // return this.store.find('entry');

       // this method returns a promise that will
       // carry the model data once it resolves
       // This is internally passed as a param of `setupController`
  },
  setupController: function (controller, model) {

       controller.set('content', model);
       // this is the same as the default implementation, so if you're *NOT* doing
       // anything different than this, get rid of `setupController` altogether

       // the `model` param, is the return of the `model` function just above. 
       // It is returned a `promise` rather than data, and will be made 
       // available once the promise is resolved, materializing the records 

       // the param doesn't have to be called `model`, but the 
       // function above *HAS* to be named `model` 
  }

});
```

I am not 100% sure, but I believe the error may be happening because you are calling   `RandomRaffle.Entry.find()` when it should be `this.store.find('entry')`

Comment: This solved my error.  Am I correct to assume that RandomRaffle.Entry.createRecord({name: this.get('newEntryName')}); should be changed to this.store.createRecord('entry', {name: this.get('newEntryName')}); as well?

Comment: Yeah. According to the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/creating-and-deleting-records/) it should be `this.store.createRecord('modelName', { key1: 'value1', keyN: 'valueN'});`

Comment: the addEntry function works as expected and persists when I add save() at the end.  My new error is this: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  The error occurs at this.get('store').commit();.  I've tried this.store.save(), and this.get('store').save().  Any ideas?

Comment: you have to call `save` on the model record. To do that, you assign the `createRecord` into a variable, maybe you wanna call it "entry", then it'd be `var entry = this.store.createRecord('entry', {...}); entry.save();`. But hey.. maybe, just maybe, you wanna go check the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/persisting-records/)?

Answer (score 0):

The models/entry.js and store.js files are correct in the original question. Plus...

router.js

```
RandomRaffler.EntriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
       return this.store.find('entry');
   }
});
```

entries_controller.js

```
RandomRaffler.EntriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

actions: {
    addEntry: function(name) {
        //Create the entry record
        var entry = this.store.createRecord('entry', {
            name: name,
            winner: false
        });
        // Save the changes
        entry.save();           
    },
```

Also you may notice in your rails server log that there is a problem with the csrf token, this can be fixed by placing this code in the first few lines of the rails controller file (eg entries_controller.rb)

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

A full working app of the Railscast project can be found at https://github.com/markwiggles/raffler